# Is it possible to remove "</tr><tr>" from a table? So that all the content is on one row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very specific problem. I'm using a fairly limited platform for a client that has a generated element of a table with up to 10 columns and unlimited rows. What I want to do is have maybe up to 25 columns and then put these columns all on a single row. Currently if I have 25 columns, it goes into 3 rows. The only limitation is that the platform only lets me use up to 10 columns wide, and doesn't let me manually change the amount of rows. And I can't edit the HTML because it's generated every page load.

Is there any way I can search within the ID of the table, find the /tr tr and delete it, or replace it with nothing?

Something like: getElementById("table.multi-cols") then find the /tr  tr and replace with ""?

Apologies for my very limited understanding of javascript

Comment: Yes. Don't use a `<table>` if you don't need one :D. Table cells as you already know are expected to live inside a `<tr>`.

Comment: What is the platform? I think that may help in answering your question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the existing HTML is not under the asker's control, that's spelled out clearly in the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck can you explain than this: *"Currently if I have 25 columns, it goes into 3 rows"*? :) seems like some kind of magic table to me.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, the generated table with 25 cells has three rows, because whatever platform is generating it only allows ten table cells per row.   The question appears to be how to convert that table after page load into a single-row, 25-column table.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right,

```css
tr {
  display: inline-flex; /* or   display: inline-block; */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Row 1 cell 1</td> <td>Row 1 cell 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2 cell 1</td> <td>Row 2 cell 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3 cell 1</td> <td>Row 3 cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

than if you want it to nowrap, set  `table { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Found a solution: 

<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.prod-related .gridp.multi-cols > tbody > tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
  jQuery( this ).children().appendTo(".prod-related .gridp.multi-cols > tbody > tr:first");
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
});
</script>